# Can't access any page now?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

So, I added some chmod and chown and a group and now I can't access any of my website when I go to it? All I get is:

```
    Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at -CENSORED MY DOMAIN- Port 80
```

Answer (score 1):

As your changes and the output indicate, you have a permissions problem. What files did you chmod/chown? It seems like the webroot isn't accessible.  I believe the default webroot is `/var/www/`, so try reverting your changes or changing the ownership back to the apache user.

Comment: How would one change the ownership back to the apache user?

Comment: Using `chown` just as you did before.  Something like `chown -r apache:apache /var/www/` would work, but that may be more files than you want.  If you still run into problems, the apache user may still not have read permissions on the files which you could fix with `chmod +r` targeted at the appropriate files.

Comment: It said "chown: invalid user: ‘apache:apache’"

Comment: help please mate